# App inventor blocks in LaTex

Tags: packages, package-writing

My question is very simple...

Is their a package to write the scratch like blocks in LaTeX. So I can make worksheets for my students.

(There is a wonderfull scratch-package that I already use for making MakeyMakey worksheets, but I can not use this for App inventor blocks)

Comment: Like [this one](https://ctan.org/pkg/scratch?lang=en)?

Comment: @Oleinik that is the scratch-package I use for MakeyMakey things. The blocks in App inventor are different.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. Sorry for that. Taking a look at this App Inventor thing, I don't think there is a package for that, especially due to the variety of features available. It is far more complex than a simple scratch code... But I would really like seeing such a thing in LateX!

Comment: Haven't had to teach either languages, but played with both of them in the past. I'd probably start from the existing Scratch package, find a block in App Inventor that doesn't exist, and post another question  (or edit this one) about making a new block that matches. On first glance, though, the Scratch package covers most every shape that AI would use, just would need new text in some buttons.